# Using matlab to find a function minimum through secant method

Tags: matlab

`xM(t) = −11.9084 + 57.9117 cos(2πt/87.97)`, `yM(t) = 56.6741 sin(2πt/87.97)` and `xE(t) = −2.4987 + 149.6041 cos(2πt/365.25)`, `yE(t) = 149.5832 sin(2πt/365.25)` represent the positions of Mercury and Earth on an xy-plane, where the sun is at (0,0) and t is the passage of time.  I'd like to find the minimum distance between the planets over the next 1000 days by finding the minimum of the function `f(t) = ((xE(t) − xM(t))^2 + (yE(t) − yM(t))^2)^(1/2)` with a matlab program that implements the secant method.

```
function [r,N] = SECANT(x0,x1,eps,Nmax,f)
N = 1;
while (N <= Nmax) && (abs(x1-x0) >= eps)
  r = x1 - f(x1)*((x1-x0)/(f(x1)-f(x0)));
  x0 = x1;
  x1 = r;

  N = N+1;
end
r
N
```

The above is what I have for the secant method.  I think it should work, but it's possible I made a mistake with it. And this is what I have in matlab to actually solve the problem.

```
p = @(t) (((-2.4987 + 149.6041*cos(2*pi*t/365.25))-(-11.9084 + 57.9117*cos(2*pi*t/87.97))).^2+((149.5832*sin(2*pi*t/365.25))-(56.6741*sin(2*pi*t/87.97))).^2).^(1/2);
y = SECANT(x0,x1,eps,Nmax,p)
```

I know that only `p` is the appropriate thing to pass to the function.  I could make up `eps` (level of precision), and `Nmax` (maximum number of iterations), but I can't figure out what the parameters `x0` and `x1` should be.

Comment: Have you tested your function on a problem with a known solution?

Comment: Yes, my secant function accurately found an approximation for (1+5^(1/5))/2.

Comment: Have you looked at the local minimas of your cost function? If it has any, than the secant method may not converge to the global minimum. Perhaps try plotting the function to get an idea of where the local minimas are, and then run the secant method locally around each. The minimum of the local minima will be the global minimum.

Comment: Looking at your formulas, I take it Mercury has an orbital period of once every 87.97 days. Combined with the earth's period of 365.25 days, you will have several local minimums over 1000 days. I haven't thought it through, but it may be sufficient to break the 1000 days up into 87.97 day intervals, find the minimum of each, and then find the minimum of the 87.97 minimums.

Comment: Do I understand your question wrong? `x0` and `x1` seem to me the limits within which you look for the minimum. If `t` is time in days, then you set `x0=0` and `x1=1000` to find the minimum within the next 1000 days.

Comment: That's what I initially thought, but that returns  -2.8857e+138, which doesn't make sense in context.

Comment: Maybe its the method. I checked against another implementation I found online and I get garbage. The secant method is for finding roots, not general minimums. This function never goes to zero.

Comment: I think it's the method. The secant method is for finding roots, not general minimums. This function never goes to zero. I even checked against another implementation I found online and I get garbage. It's finding the intersection of where the secant line hits zero and that is very far away, which leads to larger and larger intervals rather than smaller.

Comment: My advice would be to just differentiate your cost function and use a gradient descent method. Looking at the graph of p(t) over 0 to 100, you will have to break the intervals up into intervals of 87.97 days. (I count 10 local minima.)

Comment: How much accuracy do you need? Can you just let `t=0:1/86400:1000` and find the minimum of `p(t)`? That will give you the answer to 1 second.